# Testing triggers with processing time

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Can we test a pipeline that has windows with triggers that depend on processing time? For instance a streaming pipeline with a global window and a trigger to fire on elementCountAtLeast 0 will have different outputs depending on when the data comes in, so can we simulate that in any way?

Even if not for automated tests, being able to try out different windowing strategies and see their affects would be very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally agree. We're in the process of rewriting the DirectPipelineRunner to support this. Stay tuned!

Comment: Good to know. Cheers